# Automated flow which update the same list item will raise this error "Your changes conflict with those made concurrently "

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We have this workflow which get triggered when adding/editing files inside a document library. The flow will get a list item from a custom list based on the parent folder id inside the document library >> and update one of the custom list item properties, as follow:-

[image]

The flow will run if we upload one file at a time on a parent folder, but if we drag and drop multiple files inside the same parent folder, the Update Item action will raise this error (since it will try to update the same list item):-

```
Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.
```

[image]

any advice? and if there a way to queue or handle multiple updates on the same list item?